# Julia: Finding values larger than 0 in vector with missing

Tags: julia, missing-data

I'm fairly new to Julia and as a Matlab/R User I find it, for the most part, really nice to work with.

However, I'm a little confused by the missing values and how to work with them.

Let's say I have a vector:

```
a=[missing -1 2 3 -12] #Julia
a=[NaN -1 2 3 -12] #Matlab
```

In Matlab I would just do the following to find the values below 0

```
a(a<0)
```

which gives me

```
-1 -12
```

The same unfortunately doesn't work in Julia and when I try

```
a[a.<0]
```

in Julia I just get the following error

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: unable to check bounds for indices of type Missing
```

I also tried the following

```
a[findall(skipmissing(a).<0)]
```

which gives me

```
missing
3
```

since, of course, I skipped the missing value in the findall-function. I'm pretty sure there is an easy and logical way to do this, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Can someone please show me the way?

Best,
Richard

Comment: Note that the Matlab example is not equivalent to the Julia one. If you use `NaN` instead of `missing` in Julia, then `a[a.<0]` works exactly like in Matlab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to do it:

```
julia> a=[missing -1 2 3 -12]
1×5 Array{Union{Missing, Int64},2}:
 missing  -1  2  3  -12

julia> a[isless.(a, 0)]
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  -1
 -12
```

This uses the fact that `missing` is considered larger than any number by `isless`.

Another way to write it:

```
julia> filter(x -> isless(x, 0), a)
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  -1
 -12
```

Now in order to avoid this special trick with `isless` you can do the following (using `coalesce` is a general approach that can be used for safe handling of `missing` values):

```
julia> a[coalesce.(a .< 0, false)]
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  -1
 -12
```

or

```
julia> filter(x -> coalesce(x < 0, false), a)
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  -1
 -12
```

finally you can be more explicit like:

```
julia> filter(x -> !ismissing(x) && x < 0, a)
2-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  -1
 -12
```

or

```
julia> [v for v in a if !ismissing(v) && v < 0]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
  -1
 -12
```

(you could use comprehension syntax also in the examples above)